# How to move between a Pivot Control in Windows Phone 8 programmatically

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have a situation where i need to move to different pivots on a Pivot Page in Windows Phone 8
but i am unable to find a way to achieve that.

here is the screenshot:
[image]

I want to switch to  "Map" pivot when i tap on any LongListItem.

C#+XAML+WP8

Comment: mate don't use map control inside a Panorama or Pivot this is not recommended

Comment: Alright but that did not answer my question.Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually is quite simple,just what you have to know is to which index you wanna move

```
 YourPivotControl.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot controls are largely list-based and pivot along data points.  Basically, if you have apps that are driven by list items,then Pivot control is the best bet for you:

Selecting an item in the page described has nothing to do with the Pivot control, Pivot control only helps you in going from List to AddP, via Map.

And to scroll through the pages; see example attached[image]:

Do hope this helps.

Regards